# UIButton not respond or respond slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

My problem is that I have so many `UITableViewCells` in a `UITableView`, each cell has a `UITextfield`. When I finished edit in `UITextfield`, I will tap the navigation Back Button to show another View Controller. But I need to touch the back button many times, the button will respond. I want to know why and how to fix this bug? Thanks in advance.
[This is my app screenshot. The navigation back button is in red box. There are some textfield in table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6WTX.png)

Comment: In simulator or real device?.

Comment: try to increase tappable area of button. (increase the size of button)

Comment: Add your code, what are you executing once you click back button?

Comment: Please add the screenshot or some implement code.

Comment: Are you using web service call in 'another View Controller'?

Comment: I tried with an UITableView with 10.000 items with a cell with an UIText field and it works fine.
Can you post a test case?

Comment: check your method that is getting called on back button (as in you calling other method or web service or saving the text editing).

Comment: @Signare both have the same problem

Comment: @Sakya screenshot is in link

Comment: @the_UB yes, but it doesn't seemly affect the UIbutton

Comment: Thanks everyone who concern my problem, I guess it may be gestures conflict in my view controller.